# Mysql display one colum (one with higest id) if from id and to id values matches in any of the colums

Tags: mysql

How do i display the record with highest id in  a group select using max

Perhaps an example would be clearer. Given a table called messages, I have 5 columns (id, from_id, to_id, text, created_at):

```
id: id of the message
from_id: user id of message sender 
to_id: user id of message receiver
text: the message body
created_at: the time message was sent

---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
id | from_id | to_id  |text      |created_at|
---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
1  | 1       | 2      |hello     |00000001  |
2  | 2       | 1      |hi        |00000002  |
3  | 1       | 2      |test      |00000003  |
4  | 1       | 2      |checkmg   |00000004  |
5  | 4       | 3      |you went  |00000005  |
6  | 3       | 4      |i did     |00000006  |
7  | 3       | 4      |message   |00000007  |
8  | 3       | 5      |chat tt   |00000008  |
9  | 5       | 3      |chat ts   |00000009  |
10 | 3       | 5      |test ch   |00000010  |
---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
```

If  multiple users exchange messages back and fort multiple times and i only want to display one single row per user (one with highest id)  comparing all 'from_id' and 'to_id' rows  and making sure from user 1 to user 2 and from user 2 to user 1 should be grouped and display only one with highest id number . I want my answer to look like the result below

```
---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
id | from_id | to_id  |text      |created_at|
---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
4  | 1       | 2      |checkmg   |00000004  |
7  | 3       | 4      |message   |00000007  |
10 | 3       | 5      |test ch   |00000010  |
---+---------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: you should never use [reserverd words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-in-current-series) as name in a field list.

Comment: This is only to show examples using shortest possible words and i usually use backticks if i have to .My field list are not named like this .

Comment: Then you wrote a bad example, and backtick are no excuse for what i stated .

Comment: Question has been edited to follow reserved word rules and examples has be updated . Thanks for pointing that out. An upvote would help

Comment: Database version?

Comment: MySQL version 10.2

Comment: Latest version of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/) is 8.0.23, you probably meant [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the indicated question; implicitly part of this question is how to do the group by in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Query not adapted to changed names (because of reserverd words being used, and `timestamp` is also a reserverd word!)

```
SELECT m.`id`,m.`from`,m.`to`,m.`text`,m.`timestamp`
from mytable13 m
inner join (
    select 
       max(id) as id 
    from mytable13 
    group by CASE WHEN `from`<`to` THEN `from`*1000+`to` ELSE `to`*1000+`from` END) x
            on x.id=m.id;
```

Grouping is done on (`from`*1000+`to`) this is assuming the `from` (or `to`) is never bigger than 1000. This should be changed if higher values  are possible.

output:

```
+------+------+------+---------+-----------+
| id   | from | to   | text    | timestamp |
+------+------+------+---------+-----------+
|    4 |    1 |    2 | checkmg | 00000004  |
|    7 |    3 |    4 | message | 00000007  |
|   10 |    3 |    5 | test ch | 00000010  |
+------+------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Table was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable13` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

with the following data:

```
insert into mytable13 values 
(1  , 1       , 2      ,'hello'     ,'00000001'  ),
(2  , 2       , 1      ,'hi'        ,'00000002'  ),
(3  , 1       , 2      ,'test'      ,'00000003'  ),
(4  , 1       , 2      ,'checkmg'   ,'00000004'  ),
(5  , 4       , 3      ,'you went'  ,'00000005'  ),
(6  , 3       , 4      ,'i did'     ,'00000006'  ),
(7  , 3       , 4      ,'message'   ,'00000007'  ),
(8  , 3       , 5      ,'chat tt'   ,'00000008'  ),
(9  , 5       , 3      ,'chat ts'   ,'00000009'  ),
(10 , 3       , 5      ,'test ch'   ,'00000010'  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.*
from (
    select max(id) id
    from messages
    group by least(from_id,to_id),greatest(from_id,to_id)
) ids
natural join messages m;
```